# Asp classic page to php

Tags: php, asp-classic

I have this url in classic asp:"http:/blablabla/123.asp?id=1293". My question, is there a way to pass the id number to a external php script without using the form and submit, or that is only way to do it??

My data.php script:

```
<?php

$xxx = $_POST["xxx"];

//... some code

$gantt->render_complex_sql("SELECT * FROM gantt_tasks WHERE something = '".$xxx."'" , "id", "start_date,duration,text,progress,parent","");
?>
```

My "123.asp?id=1293" page:

```
<html>
<head>
// .. scripts and title
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="post" action="data.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="xxx" value="Request.QueryString("id")" />
</form>
    <div id="gantt_here" style='width:100%; height:100%;'></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        gantt.init("gantt_here");
        gantt.load("data.php");

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And i dont want to use the "Response.Redirect" page either.

Comment: Where does ASP.Net come into play?

Comment: Wouldn't `<a href="http:/blablabla/123.asp?id=1293">TEXT</a>` do it for you? or are you asking how to access the `id` on the PHP page?

Comment: the id is in the asp page, and i want that id number in a external php script, data.php in this case

Comment: The link doesn't work as a solution? Also the `render_complex_sql` I think opens you to SQL injections unless that function some how can distinguish user input from your query.

Comment: Can you change your PHP page to retrieve the values via `$_GET` instead of `$_POST`? Then just forward the ASP querystring params to the PHP page

Comment: your ASP isn't even valid ASP `<input type="hidden" name="xxx" value="Request.QueryString("id")" />` That's wrong.

Comment: See my answer. You have to pass the query param.

Comment: @HenriS. So you just regurgitate Bonds comment and post it as your own answer. Classy move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

UPDATE:

```
gantt.load('data.php?id=<%= Request.QueryString("id") %>');
```

But it sounds very strange using old asp files and php files in the same project.